# How to set data into woocemmerce session from a input field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a plugin where user can add a custom price and able to "add to cart" for a specific product. Now I'm able to add the custom value to the cart but nothing show when I goto another page (cart/checkout). It seems it reset.

so I try something like this but it did not worked.

```
 $data = $_POST['product_price'];
 WC()->session->set( 'custom_price' , $data );
 $retrive_price = WC()->session->get( 'custom_price' );
```

How to set value and get the value from session

```
$retrive_price = 'data_from_woocommerce_session';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, i am showing you another approach. you can do it in the following way

1st page:

```
 session_start();
 $data = $_POST['product_price'];
 $_SESSION['custom_price']=$data;
```

Now in another page write the following to receive the value:

```
 session_start();
 $retrive_price =  $_SESSION['custom_price'];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately not working it show an error on another page

Comment: Actually I try to move data from product page to cart or checkout page

Comment: well thenit wont work.because it has no relationship with woo commerce built in  session.

Comment: you can remove session_start(); line . it will remove that notice

Comment: Yes try this too but after new page load nothing storrd on session

Comment: it solved just put the `session_start();` top of all line of code